# How to join a negative polygon with inner negative polygons?

Tags: c++, boost, polygon

I'm currently working on a private project which depends on some operations on polygons using the Boost C++ Libraries.

I'm currently trying to work with the inner polygon/negative polygon concept.

What I need to do now is to join three polygons where two of them have a positive (counterclockwise) outer polygon and an negative (clockwise) inner polygon.

The third one is a negative polygon a new polygon object with a negative area - points in clockwise direction. And this is the point where I'm not fully sure how to handle the situation.

Here's a picture of those three polygons. The middle one which connects the left upper polygon with the right lower one is the negative one.

[image: Polygons including the negative one]

Now what I would like to do is to join all three polygons through the union function.
What I expect union to do is to cut away the positive parts of the polygons 1 and 3 (the positive polygons) and return the remaining two polygons of 1 and 3.

What I actually get are my polygons 1 and 3 untouched as there would be no negative polygon 2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

What I need to get is a vector not a bitmap or a picture or whatever. 
These Picture are just used to better visualize what I have and what I need.

Those three Polygons are actually not more than an vector of x and y points.

Here's a picture of what I would expect to be the correct result of union of all three polygons:

Edit2: Corrected the result

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you add a picture of intended output?

Comment: Your expected result does not look right. Are these polygons? If so, why is the boundary looks so strange? I thought your original polygons were square "donuts". In that case the negative polygon should just bite the pieces out of those donuts, turning them into C-shaped polygons.

Comment: You are a 100% right. I corrected my picture now and that should be what I actually expect...

Answer (score 0):

How do you want unions to work? [Usually a union of polygons 1 and 2 would result in  polygon 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEGOS.png), but I suspect for your use case you want it to result in polygon 4. If that's the case, you can simply do a union of all the clockwise paths, then do a union of the counterclockwise paths, then take the difference of the former from the latter. If you want the union to result in polygon 3, then I don't think there's a consistent way to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Good plan is to consider your polygons as a bitmap (of booleans):
Every polygon will be blit to a bitmap of type (R,R)->bool. Once it's in bitmap format, negative polygons are just andnot-operations on the booleans:

```
class Bitmap { virtual bool Map(float x, float y) const=0; };
class AndNot : public Bitmap {
public:
   AndNot(Bitmap &bm1, Bitmap &bm2) : bm1(bm1), bm2(bm2) { }
   bool Map(float x, float y) const {
      return b1.Map(x,y) && !b2.Map(x,y);
   }
private:
   Bitmap &bm1, &bm2;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this will help me as I don't need bitmaps neither bool's